# Why does RedisManager property removed from ServiceStack/Service.cs file?

Tags: redis, connection, servicestack, servicestack.redis

Previously we had a RedisManager property in the version of 4.0.50 but in the latest version this property is removed. Can anyone know why it is been removed? What is the replacement for it?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be Multitenancy compatible, the RedisManager was replaced with [Redis property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/af02e74a04915165308669f86e21ff96a4487b08/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L59) which resolves a new `IRedisClient` instance from `GetRedisClient()`, the behavior of which can be overridden in your AppHost. This also reduces boilerplate as you can access the `Redis` instance directly from your Service, e.g:

```
Redis.SetValue("foo", "bar");
var bar = Redis.GetValue("foo");
```

If needed the `RedisManager` property can still be accessed in your Services like any other dependency by adding a public property:

```
public IRedisClientsManager  RedisManager { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz for the reply.